# How to modify django manytomany relationship default input selection form to Multiple Search Selection?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

**django manytomany relationship default input selection form**

[default multiple selection form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pqU3.png)

**Multiple Search Selection dowpdown**

[Multiple Search Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGYro.png)

> Using default django class based Viewsto create form is not
>   userfriendly in case of manytomany realtionship model

```
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
```

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal. Hopefully this will help you a bit